# Codeigniter, Get uri->segment(1) as a parameter and not as a controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

Consider a sample url as : `http://localhost/project/ABCD`
(where `'http://localhost/project/'` is base_url() and 'ABCD' would be consider as controller.)

Whenever I'll make request with this url, i want my 'home.php' controller to run its index function(which is default route) and make that index function accept 'ABCD' as a parameter.

so 'ABCD' should become parameter, not controller or method.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One you can try to do is adding index in your URL, so you call it as `http://localhost/project/index/ABCD` where ABCD is parameter for your index function
it is stated in CodeIgniter documentation
[CodeIgniter Controllers](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)
hope this helps

Comment: can't use index.php in url. but just got the solution. and have posted it here ↓

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved. Its easy.
Write in your route.php file the following line:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index';
```

this way 
`http://localhost/project/` will redirect to **welcome** controller

and `http://localhost/project/ABCD` will redirect to **home/index** controller with **ABCD** as an parameter to index function

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'home/index/$1';
```

Be warned that:

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

so `(:any)` route should remain at the end of the routes list.
[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).